# Has anyone tried decision transformers with PPO?

Tags: transformer, proximal-policy-optimization, online-learning

I am trying to implement a PPO agent to try and solve (or at least get a good solution) for eternity 2 a tile matching game where each tile has 4 colored size you have to minimize the number of conflict between adjacent edges.

I thought that using a decision transformer would be a good way to go, since transformers should be good at 'understanding' the relationship between the pieces. I am trying to get the Decision Transformer to predict what next tile should be played, but i am getting nowhere and my policy does not seem to learn anything.

The value loss converges but the policy loss stays around a constant mean. Are decision transformers not very compatible with PPO or am i missing something?

If you want to take a look here is the code.
https://github.com/mt-clemente/Projet_INF6201/tree/transformer/Network